# Does $E(XU)\neq 0$ imply $E(f(X) U)\neq 0$ "almost always"?

Tags: st.statistics, expectation, random-functions

Consider two non-orthogonal random variables
$$
(1) \quad E(XU)\neq 0,
$$
where $X$ can be a vector.
Can we claim that (1) implies that $U$ will be "generically" non-orthogonal to any function $f$ of $X$, i.e.
$$
(2) \quad E(f(X) U)\neq 0\quad ?
$$
For instance, consider $X\equiv (X_1, X_2)$ and $f(X)=X_1\cdot X_2$.

Can we characterise a "large enough" class of such functions $f$?

**Thoughts (1):** I find this problem quite tricky. $E(XU)\neq 0$ does not always imply $E(f(X)U)\neq 0$. For instance, take $X$ scalar and the function $f(X)=X^k$ with $k$ even. Suppose $(X,U)$ are symmetric around zero. Then, even if $E(XU)\neq 0$, it   holds that
$$
E(X^k U)=0.
$$
However, I wonder if this counterexample is just a very special case and we might be able to characterise a large class of functions $f$ such that (1) implies (2).

**Thoughts (2):** If you are familiar with endogeneity in ordinary least squares (OLS), you will know that if $E(XU)\neq 0$, then  the OLS estimator is inconsistent. An instrument $Z$ is a variable that is orthogonal to $U$ and can help us "clean" the non-orthogonality of $X$. However, I never found a book suggesting as instrument a deterministic transformation of $X$, such as $f(X)$. Books always suggest to use different random variables. This makes me think that "in general" (1) should imply (2).

Comment: It is not true that "$E(XU)=0$ implies $E(f(X) U)= 0$". More importantly, "generically" we always have $EVU\ne0$ and even $EZ\ne0$ for random variables $U,V,Z$ -- just because a "generically" chosen real number is not $0$. So, for your question to acquire a meaning, it needs to be much more specific.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the wrong statement.  I don't know how to be more specific, though. Are you saying that (2) is generically true and, hence, the question (1) implies (2) does not make sense?

Comment: To answer you question, I need to know what you mean by "generically".

Comment: Yes, I see the point. Can you help figure out a notion of "generically" that makes sense here? Given my counterexample, I cannot think of any.

Comment: I cannot think of a reasonable definition of "generically" to make this work. Rather, I think this is impossible. But to prove the impossibility, one would need a rigorous definition of"generically".

Comment: Just one more clarifying question: consider a variation of the statement to "$E(U|X)\neq 0$  implies $E(U|f(X))\neq 0$ for any $f$ (measurable, perhaps?)". Does this statement hold now?

Comment: No, this is not true. E.g., let $P(X=\pm1)=1/2$, $U=X$, and $f(x)=x^2$.